# Open existing folder with command button

Tags: vba, directory

The code below is not recognizing existing folders.

I tested searching for Shop Order Number MSO-40550 (the code searches "40550" only).

Hovering over the line:

```
strFullPath = strP & strC & "\" & strGc & "\" & strT
```

showed the correct path to folder 40550:

```
\\cftanaus1fs01\ASO_MSO\40000-49999\40500-40599\40550
```

Shop Order Folders are organized in this hierarchy:

```
 Parent Folder Name: ASO_MSO

    Child Folder Name: 40000-49999
 
       Grandchild Folder Name: 40500-40599
    
         Target Folder Name: 40550 (used in this example)
```

Actions

1. Open Userform
2. Search for a Shop Order Number (example: MSO-40550)
3. Click on a command button to open the corresponding folder in Windows Explorer

```vb
Private Sub cmbOpenFolder_Click()
    Const strP = "\\cftanaus1fs01\ASO_MSO\" 'Parent folder
    Dim strC As String 'Child folder, ex: 40000-49999
    Dim strGc As String 'Grandchild folder, ex: 40500-40599
    Dim strT As String 'Target folder, ex: 40550
    Dim strFullPath As String 'Full path
    Dim fso As Object
    strC = Left(txtSuffix, 1) & "0000-" & Left(txtSuffix, 1) & "9999" 'Child folder, ex: 40000-49999
    strGc = Left(txtSuffix, 3) & "00-" & Left(txtSuffix, 3) & "99" 'Grandchild folder, ex: 40500-40599
    strT = txtSuffix 'Target folder, ex: 40550
    strFullPath = strP & strC & "\" & strGc & "\" & strT  'Full path
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   ' Create FileSystemObject
    If fso.FolderExists(strT) = True Then ' Check whether folder exists
       'MsgBox "Here you go!"
       Shell "explorer.exe " & strFullPath, vbNormalFocus  ' Open it
   Else
       MsgBox "This folder does not exist."
       'fso.CreateFolder strFullPath ' Code if you wanted to create a folder.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: `If fso.folderExists(strFullPath) = True Then`

Comment: @niton - good catch

Comment: @niton I changed the code per your recommendation. I tested it by clicking on an existing folder, but I get the message: "This folder does not exist."

Comment: What does `Debug.Print strFullPath` say? Appears you are missing `Option Explicit` which would give a hint `txtSuffix` would be blank.

Comment: Ok, so I added Debug.Print strFullPath. I searched for an existing folder "40544". I got the same message, but the Immediate window shows the correct path as follows: \\cftanaus1fs01\ASO_MSO\40000-49999\40500-40599\40544

Comment: Copy the path directly from the immediate window into Windows Explorer. If the folder opens put  `Shell "explorer.exe " & strFullPath, vbNormalFocus` just after `strFullPath = strP & strC & "\" & strGc & "\" & strT` to see the true message not the MsgBox message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different way to handle the folder grouping hierarchy:

**EDIT3**: cleaned up and added check for partial folder name, fixed `Dir()` code

```vb
Option Explicit

Const FOLDER_ROOT As String = "\\cftanaus1fs01\ASO_MSO\" 'Parent folder

Private Sub cmbOpenFolder_Click()
    
    Dim strFullPath As String, fso As Object, txt As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   ' Create FileSystemObject
    
    txt = txtSuffix 'get the user entry
    If Len(txt) > 0 Then
        strFullPath = VerifiedFolderPath(txt)
        Debug.Print "Path: " & strFullPath
        'safer to quote the folder path, in case it has spaces
        Shell "explorer.exe """ & strFullPath & """", vbNormalFocus  ' Open it
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a folder number", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub

'construct and verify a folder path, checking for partial name
Function VerifiedFolderPath(srch As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, flr As Long, n, f
    i = CLng(srch)
    VerifiedFolderPath = FOLDER_ROOT           'parent folder
    For Each n In Array(10000, 100)    'loop each level of grouping
        flr = Application.Floor(i, n)
        VerifiedFolderPath = VerifiedFolderPath& flr & "-" & (flr + (n - 1)) & "\"
    Next n
    'check for existing matched folder, including partial match
    f = Dir(VerifiedFolderPath & srch & "*", vbDirectory)
    If Len(f) = 0 Then                     'not found?
        MsgBox "No folder was found matching: " & vbLf & VerifiedFolderPath & "*", _
               vbExclamation, "Folder not found"
        VerifiedFolderPath = ""                    'return empty string
    Else
        VerifiedFolderPath = VerifiedFolderPath & f & "\"  'found: add matched folder name and terminating \
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tim! I may give your code a try. What does the ("3"), ("447"), ("44549") represent?

Comment: That would be whatever the user typed in to `txtSuffix`

Comment: Are these procedures in addition to the code I created? Because I execute on a command button click.

Comment: See my edit above for how it might look in your use case.

Comment: Great! I'll give this a try.

Comment: Now, I get the other message: "Please enter a folder number."

Comment: Sorry I had added a variable declaration for txtSuffix so my code compiled, and forgot to remove it when posting.  Fixed above

Comment: I think I figured out why things aren't working and kind of embarrassed to admit this. When the target folder is created, the name is just 5-digits, ex: 40544. However, once I 'fill' the folder with files, I updated the folder name with additional details, i.e., 40544 Customer Name_End User_Product. So, I am only looking for the 5 digits. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Ok, I'll try your code with the txtSuffix before I do anything to mess this up:)

Comment: No luck. I even searched for a folder that only has 5 digits that match the txtSuffix exactly and I still get: "Please enter a folder number."
Also, the Debug.Print codes are not appearing in the Immediate window.
Lastly, f2 As Long - I don't see f2 again in the code.

Comment: @niton code works if I search for a folder named the suffix only, ex: 40599. However, someday, that folder name will expand to include the Customer Name, etc. I need to rework the code to only read the first 5 digits of the folder name. Then I think I've got it.

Comment: Did you remove the variable declaration for `txtSuffix`?  Are you reading the user-entered value and getting the correct entry into `txt`?

Comment: If you only have a partial name for the final folder you can use (eg) `Dir("\\cftanaus1fs01\ASO_MSO\40000-49999\40500-40599\40544*", vbDirectory)` to get the actual folder name (assuming in that example there's only one folder which begins with "40544".  Note you don't include the final \ in the call to `Dir()`

Comment: The original code above works if the folder name only contains the suffix. If the folder contains the suffix + customer name, it doesn't work. So, I tried adding Dir as follows: 
strFullPath = Dir(strP & strC & "\" & strGc & "\" & strT & *,vbDirectory) and I get a Syntax error.

Comment: `Dir()` takes a full folder path (with or without wildcards in the last part of the path) and returns (assuming a match) *only the name of the matched folder*.  My code was wrong there, so I've fixed that part.

Comment: Hi Tim! I'm getting a Compile Error: Variable not defined. It is highlighting this line in yellow: Function VerifiedFolderPath(srch As String) As String and it is also selecting the text: FolderPath in the line FolderPath = FOLDER_ROOT

Comment: Did you include the `Const FOLDER_ROOT As String = ...` at the top of the module?

Comment: Yes, At the very top of the userform code, I have...
Option Explicit
Const FOLDER_ROOT As String = "\\cftanaus1fs01\ASO_MSO\" 'Parent folder

FOLDER_ROOT is defined As String, but FolderPath is not defined. Could that be it? FolderPath As String?

Comment: Ok, so I tested adding: FolderPath As String. The error disappeared. File Explorer opens to "This PC", not to the correct folder. We're getting closer Tim:)

Comment: Sorry I've been lazy and not been testing my own code so I made a few more fixes above.  I should take a week off.

Comment: I understand and greatly appreciate your help. I copied your code. I get a Compile Error: Variable not defined and it 'selects' FolderPath in the code line:  MsgBox "No folder was found matching: " & vbLf & FolderPath & "*", _

Comment: I just added:  Dim FolderPath As String and it works!!! You are so patient with me and I am so pleased to have this working.  I wish I could buy you a cup of coffee and a danish.

Comment: I would like to show you the final code with notes I added. I'm trying to understand what's actually going on and would like to see if I understand it. Is that ok with you, Tim?

Comment: Sure that’s fine with me

Comment: Comments limit how much I can copy/paste. How do I enter the entire code to show you?

Comment: I'll email you...

Comment: Replied via email